# spring-boot-admin client custom health-url Invalid

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I want to custom client properties, "health-url","management-url","service-url". Here is properties in application.properties.

```
spring.boot.admin.client.health-url= http://localhost:8080/registry/health
spring.boot.admin.client.management-url= http://localhost:8080/registry
spring.boot.admin.client.service-url= http://localhost:8080/registry
```

The default properties is

```
managementUrl=http://localhost:8080, 
healthUrl=http://localhost:8080/health, 
serviceUrl=http://localhost:8080,
```

But the properties are ignored.
I find the issue [Admin Starter Client ignoring Service](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/135), 
However the properties is not useful

```
spring.boot.admin.client.ignoreUnknownFields=true
```

How can I change the properties?

Comment: Change them in application.properties

Comment: I have do this, but it doesn't change.

Comment: which version are you using??

Comment: spring boot: 1.5.1, spring boot admin: 1.5.2

Comment: Did you check the `/env` endpoint of your client application that your properties values are present in your ApplicationContext

Comment: If this properties is ok, I can invoke "registry/env", but I can't. It still run with "/env"